# Making a shape a const, and using it multiple times in js

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a pixelated image by hand, but the editor im using does not allow copy and pasting, which means I have to type everything by hand, so defining a new rectangle each time I wanna use it is too much work.

What I tried was:

```
const grey = new Rectangle(10, 10);
grey.setPosition (100, 400);
grey.setColor ("#686968");
add (grey);
grey. setPosition (110, 400);
grey.setColor("#686968");
add (grey);
```

But instead of adding another grey square, it just moved the first one.

I also looked online and did not find anything that helped.

Comment: We don't know what `Rectangle` is

Comment: Just create a function that returns rectangles. Then re-use it instead of copy and pasting the code.

Comment: Wdym? // To make a rectangle
let rect = new Rectangle(width, height);

Comment: *"instead of adding another grey square, it just moved the first one"* - Because there's only one `new Rectangle()` in the code shown.  If you want to make another new rectangle, you'd do: `grey = new Rectangle(10, 10);`  (Which means using `let` instead of `const` of course.)

Comment: It shouldn't be surprising that setting the position of something and then setting its position again moves it to the last place you set its position to be. It shouldn't be surprising that if you want to create two new rectangles then you need to write the line of code that creates a rectangle for *each* one. Write functions to reduce code duplication.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions) that makes the `Rectangle` for you, based on some parameters:

```
function getColoredRectangle(color, x, y, width = 10, height = 10, ) {
    const rect = new Rectangle(width, height);
    rect.setPosition(x, y);
    rect.setColor(color);
    return rect;
}

add(getColoredRectangle("#686968", 100, 400))
add(getColoredRectangle("#123456", 110, 400))
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven’t tried it yet, but it definitely looks like what I want.

Comment: Now I don’t have to manually type so much stuff.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, variable are passed par reference to functions. So when you call the `add` twice, it calls it with the same object.

If you want to copy your rectangle, you need to create a new object from the first one and pass this new object to the `add` function, the second time.

```js
const grey = new Rectangle(10, 10);
grey.setPosition (100, 400);
grey.setColor ("#686968");
add (grey);

const newRectangle = /** create a new rectangle from gray **/
newRectangle. setPosition (110, 400);
newRectangle.setColor("#686968");

add (newRectangle);
```

We don't know anything about the `Rectangle` class, so we cannot help you on the specific of how to create the new rectangle, but this should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: Very good explanation :) helped me with my stuff as well